# Oracle Embedded LDAP Error

Tags: ldap, oracle-11g, weblogic

I just installed the Oracle Weblogic Server. The server start fines and I can get to the admin console and use it, but once I deploy the console I begin to get exceptions on the server and it pegs the processor at 100%.

The expection is :

```
<Nov 4, 2009 11:14:00 PM EST> <Critical> <EmbeddedLDAP> <BEA-000000> <java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
at com.octetstring.vde.EntryChanges.readBytes(EntryChanges.java:274)
at com.octetstring.vde.EntryChanges.<init>(EntryChanges.java:72)
at com.octetstring.vde.replication.BackendChangeLog.getChange(BackendChangeLog.java:548)
at com.octetstring.vde.replication.Replicator.run(Replicator.java:180)
at com.octetstring.vde.replication.Replication.run(Replication.java:339)
```

The exception is repeated about every second.

I haven't tried to use the LDAP server for anything. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have to delete (or rename) the domain/servers/server_name/data/ldap directory. Be careful to have read/write access to the new dir you create before restarting Admin server.